# android: showing 1 correct and wrong item

Tags: android

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from sentmessages", null);
    /*cursor.moveToFirst();
    dataToInsert = dataToInsert + cursor.getString(1) + '\n';*/

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("aaaa")).concat(String.valueOf("\n"));



    String dataToInsert = "";
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("bbbb")).concat(String.valueOf("\n"));

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("cccc")).concat(String.valueOf("\n"));

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("dddd")).concat(String.valueOf("\n"));

    shdb.setText(dataToInsert);
```

The fowllowing code shows

> aaaa and ...

what code shall i replace for it to show

> aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd

Comment: ... might be ellipsize end of the textview.

Comment: @Rudra did u post the code in wrong order? Because, how u can use **dataToInsert** before declaring it?

Comment: Show the value in what?  `shdb` is of what type ?

Comment: Sorry for the late respone.

Comment: Shdb is of type TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this and try

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from sentmessages", null);
String dataToInsert = "";
cursor.moveToFirst();
dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("aaaa")).concat(String.valueOf(", "));

cursor.moveToFirst();
dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("bbbb")).concat(String.valueOf(", "));

cursor.moveToFirst();
dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("cccc")).concat(String.valueOf(", "));

cursor.moveToFirst();
dataToInsert = dataToInsert.concat(String.valueOf("dddd")).concat(String.valueOf(", "));

shdb.setText(dataToInsert);
```

Comment: I should say this match the needs, even if this is a bit simple ;) Depending on the size of the component used